# JNA using C DLL

Tags: jna

I'm using JNA with C DLL file and I have an exception that I can't resolve:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: lecteur.$proxy0 cannot be cast to
>   com.sun.jna.Library

Here is my source code:

```
package lecteur;

import java.util.HashMap;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Lecteur {

interface NativeInterface extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
boolean GetApiErrorString(String pcErrorString, int mxLen); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Object> nameMapping = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    nameMapping.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, StdCallLibrary.FUNCTION_MAPPER);
    nameMapping.put(Library.OPTION_CALLING_CONVENTION, StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION);
    NativeInterface instanceInterface = 
    (NativeInterface) Native.loadLibrary("MVXAPI", NativeInterface.class, nameMapping);     
    String pcErrorString= "AOD";
    int MaxLen = 275;
    System.out.println(instanceInterface.GetApiErrorString(pcErrorString, MaxLen));

  }

}
```

I need your help everybody.

Answer (score 0):

1. extend `StdCallLibrary` rather than `StdCallCallback`.
2. `GetApiErrorString` *probably* has the wrong signature.  If the function expects to be able to write to the buffer you're passing it, you need to use `byte[]` rather than `String`.  Passing `String` gives the native code a read-only buffer.

**EDIT**

3. You may also need to use a `StdCallFunctionMapper` if your exported functions have the form `funcname@NN`.

   options = new HashMap();
   options.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, new StdCallFunctionMapper());
   lib = NativeLibrary.loadLibrary("mylib", options);

From the [JNA FAQ](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#calling-nativeloadlibrary-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror):

> **My library mapping causes an UnsatisfiedLinkError**
>
> Use a dump utility to examine the names of your exported functions to
>   make sure they match (nm on linux, depends on Windows). On Windows, if
>   the functions have a suffix of the form "@NN", you need to pass a
>   StdCallFunctionMapper as an option when initializing your library
>   interface.

Comment: When i change String to byte [ ] I have new exception:

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetApiErrorString': The specified procedure could not be found, It is caused by the signature of the function wich is:    int GetApiErrorString ( char *, int);